Is the word "niragodha" mentioned in any scriptures?
I have recently learned "Niragodha", the Sanskrit word for Water Dragon. But, does any scriptures mention the word "Niragodha"?

how did you come by this word nirogadha?

Well, i learned the word "Niragodha" in the learnsanskrit website, sometimes ago. So, asked if it is mention in any scriptures.
